# How determine if range list contains specified integer

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join, plpgsql

Product type table contains product types. Some ids may missing :

```
create table artliik (liiginrlki char(3) primary key);
insert into artliik values('1');
insert into artliik values('3');
insert into artliik values('4');
...
insert into artliik values('999');
```

Property table contais comma separated list of types.

```
create table strings ( id char(100) primary key, kirjeldLku chr(200) );
insert into strings values ('item1', '1,4-5' );
insert into strings values ('item2', '1,2,3,6-9,23-44,45' );
```

Type can specified as single integer, e.q 1,2,3 or as range like 6-9  or 23-44
List can contain both of them.

How to all properties for given type.
Query

```
select id 
from artliik
join strings on ','||trim(strings.kirjeldLku)||',' like '%,'||trim(artliik.liiginrlki)||',%'
```

returns date for single integer list only.
How to change join so that type ranges in list like 6-9 are also returned?
Eq. f list contains 6-9, Type 6,7,8 and 9 shoud included in report.

Postgres 13 is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a helper function similar to `unnest` that honors ranges.

**Corrected function**

```sql
create or replace function unnest_ranges(s text)
returns setof text language sql immutable as
$$
 with t(x) as (select unnest(string_to_array(s, ',')))
 select generate_series
 (
   split_part(x, '-', 1)::int, 
   case when x ~ '-' then split_part(x, '-', 2)::int else x::int end,
   1
 )::text
 from t;
$$;
```

Then you can 'normalize' table `strings` and join.

```sql
select * 
from artliik a 
join (select id, unnest_ranges(kirjeldLku) from strings) as t(id, v)
on a.liiginrlki = v;
```

The use of a function definition is of course optional. I prefer it because the function is generic and reusable.

Comment: Creating function throws `set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
HINT: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.` How to fix this? Should union with where clauses used insted of case?

Comment: I think it should work if in the helper funct you change `select case ... from t;` into: `select unnest(case when x ~ '-' then array(select generate_series(split_part(x, '-', 1)::int, split_part(x, '-', 2)::int, 1)::text) else array[x] end) from t;`

Comment: I wrote & tested it on PG 9.5. Maybe newer versions are stricter. See corrected answer.

Comment: Yes, corrected version gives the same output as my verbose remedy (PG 14.3).

Answer (score 0):

[**dbfiddle.uk demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f1f2d6e39f48fd3de0b9c3391bb30433) will only works on pg14, since only pg14 have multirange data type. But customizeable icu collation works in pg13.
Collation doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html

---

Idea: create a multirange text data type that will sort numeric value based on their numerical value. like 'A-21' < 'A-123'.

```
CREATE COLLATION testcoll_numeric (
    provider = icu,
    locale = '@colNumeric=yes'
);

CREATE TYPE textrange AS RANGE (
    subtype = text,
    multirange_type_name = mulitrange_of_text,
    COLLATION = testcoll_numeric
);
```

So

```
SELECT
    mulitrange_of_text (textrange ('1'::text, '11'::text)) @> '9'::text AS contain_9;
```

should  return **true**.

artliik table structure remain the same, but strings table need to change a bit.

```
CREATE temp TABLE strings (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    kirjeldLku mulitrange_of_text
);
```

then query it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    strings.id
FROM
    artliik,
    strings
WHERE
    strings.kirjeldLku @> liiginrlki::text
ORDER BY
    1;
```